# I use pm2 but why can't I run an react app permanently?

Tags: reactjs, pm2, forever

I can't run the react app on Windows 10 permanently.[my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aC0yw.png)

I tried PM2 and Forever and set ExecutionPolicy to unrestricted, but it doesn't work.[what I tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxdD4.png)

I don't know what to do. Could you please tell me what I should do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.